How to retrieve ActionCadence data from Salesforce API
I'm trying to retrieve ActionCadence data from Salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_actioncadence.htm
But when I try to execute the query select COUNT() from ActionCadence, it returned an error:
sObject type 'ActionCadence' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

How could I get this data?

Go into Setup -> Sales Engagement Settings -> Automate -> Turn on Sales Engagement, then assign these permission sets to your user and try again

Sales Engagement Basic
The Sales Engagement Quick Cadence Creator
The Sales Engagement User
The Sales Engagement Cadence Creator

